Apache2 CORS headers not updating after being set
I'm hosting both back and front end in different hosts in Debian 12 (bookworm). The backend is a PHP 8.2.26 api on localhost:81 ,  using apache2. Front end is Vue running from localhost:5173.
I kept getting the CORS error in the browser:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:81/my-api/api/login.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

I fixed it with by adding header lines in /etc/apache/apache2.conf and /etc/apache/sites-available/my-api.conf files (I know there's not need for updating both apache2.conf and sites-available/my-api.conf, but I was sort of desperate):
It was not updating at all, and I kept getting the CORS error. After I disabled and re enabled Enhanced Tracking Protection on Firefox, it seemed to have been updated then, allowing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (as it was set then).
This is what I keep getting from this curl command:
$ curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost:81" --head http://localhost:5173
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Etag: W/"c8c-4Kjk1ozW+GKK4EON9SiGGxhiMJY"
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2024 15:26:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

Now I wanna set the server with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:5173, and it doesn't update at all after I set the headers.
in /etc/apache/apache2.conf:
<Directory /var/www/my-api>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted 
        
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:5173/"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
    
    Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"



    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]localhost:5173/"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
    
    Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"



    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</Directory>

/etc/apache/sites-available/my-api.conf:
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-api
    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:5173/"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

For debugging, I tried commenting out all these header lines (theoretically disabling cross origin access):
in /etc/apache/apache2.conf:
<Directory /var/www/myapi>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted 
        
#   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:5173/"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"  
#   Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"



    
#   RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]localhost:5173/"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
    
#   Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
#   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"



    
#   RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</Directory>

/etc/apache/sites-available/my-api.conf:
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-api
    
#   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:5173/"
#   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
#   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

and then resetting the both the:

Apache server with sudo systemctl reload apache2 in cmd
PHP back end with Ctrl + C and then running it again with sudo php -S localhost:81 in cmd
Vue front end with Ctrl + C and then npm run dev.

The headers set in the php api file are also commented out:
// header('Content-Type: application/json');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173/');  // Allows all origins, can be a specific origin like "https://example.com"
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Origin');
// header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
// header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

Funnily enough I keep getting the cross origin Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header from the curl command:
$ curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost:81" --head http://localhost:5173
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Etag: W/"c8c-4Kjk1ozW+GKK4EON9SiGGxhiMJY"
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2024 16:34:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

. It just doesn't seem to update whenever I update those apache2.conf and my-api.conf files.
I keep getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * even after commenting out the header lines in apache2.conf and my-app.conf that allow cross-origin access.
I tried using sudo a2dissite my-app and then sudo a2ensite my-app and then reloading both back end, front end , and apache2 server. It simply does not update and I keep getting that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header.
I also tried setting the module for headers but they are enabled already:
$ sudo a2enmod headers
Module headers already enabled

Everytime I do any of these changes, I reset both back end, front end, and apache2, but I keep getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. It doesn't update
I'm not using .htaccess files.
Where am I getting this Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * from? oO'
I wanna be able to manage CORS and I'm failing at it. =\

You got front- and backend the wrong way around, in those cURL requests. Your frontend is running under :5173 - so that's your origin of the request, that you want to simulate here. And the target of your request is your API, :81. So you want -H "Origin: http://localhost:5173" --head http://localhost:81 in those cURL requests.
